# Trying to load a picture in a cell when returning from push segue

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a table view with a custom cell.  My cell has an image on the left, and the image is a black png that I have switch to a white png when it is selected.  The cell also has a push segue attached.  My problem is when the back button is pressed in the destination view and you return to the table view, the icon is still white, so it looks like it disappeared.  I need to load the black icon back in.  I can't use didDeselectRowAtIndexPath, because the view is unloaded before it has an opportunity for this to kick in.  Is there another method that's out there that I just don't know about?  This is my current code:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *array = [self.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    StartRow *rowobject = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    StartCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.mainIcon.image = rowobject.iconWhite;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSArray *array = [self.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        StartRow *rowobject = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        StartCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.mainIcon.image = rowobject.icon;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually *don't* want to reloadData each time the table view about to appear. Instead you want to [find the index path for the currently selected cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow) and then use this knowledge to [hunt down said cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a).

After you've found the cell that's selected, you simply swap out the image.

Comment: But when I return to the view, there's no currently selected cell anymore, is there?  So do I need to push that index path into the next view, then push it back when I return to my table view?

Comment: Did you not try? Because yes, it is still selected until you return to that view, so you can see where you came from. Just take a look at any of apple's apps that have tableviews. (ie. Notes)

Comment: Awesome, it works!  I just didn't realize there was still a selected row once the view disappeared, but it totally makes sense that it's still selected.  I had to make the table view an IBOutlet and connect it in storyboard because I couldn't think of a more efficient way to find it.  But then I just found the index path for the selected row and went to the code I already put in at didDeselectRowatIndexPath.

Thanks again for your help.  I'm very new to Xcode and Obj-C in general, so every day I find something new I don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

in viewwillappear write this
[tableview reloadData];

Comment: Using reloadData for this sort of problem is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.